# Jenkinsfile - Combine variables to call a 3rd variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm wondering if the below scenario is possible.  I am trying to place some logic in a pipeline to combine two variables to call a 3rd.  With the below I'm defining food and in the 1st each loop adding the '_juice'.  At this point I would like to iterate through the array 'chips_juice' but it just returns single characters.

Any help would be appreciated

```
def food = ['chips']
def chips_juice = ['lovely-meal']

food.each { grub ->
  env.meal = grub + '_juice'
  meal.each {dinner ->
    println dinner
  }
}
```

> Results

```
[Pipeline] echo
c
[Pipeline] echo
h
[Pipeline] echo
i
[Pipeline] echo
p
[Pipeline] echo
s
[Pipeline] echo
_
[Pipeline] echo
j
[Pipeline] echo
u
[Pipeline] echo
i
[Pipeline] echo
c
[Pipeline] echo
e
[Pipeline] node
```

I have tried defining the meal variable in different formats but this either stops the pipeline or returns the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve this the way you are trying it. But you can do something like the below.

```
food = ['chips']
chips_juice = ['lovely-meal']

food.each { grub ->
  def meal = grub + '_juice'
  def newList = this.getBinding().getVariable(meal);

  newList.each {dinner ->
    println dinner
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ycr I would have never worked this out.  Much appreciated for taking the time to respond.